implementing OpenCv in python3 gstreamer code
i have a good working code with python3 gstreamer that can stream data to a server and to an appsink , i want to use the data sent via an appsink and process it with opencv so that i can display and Save.
i have tried to that in the code bellow but the display and the stream are glitching and the playback of the saved video is accelerated .
i would like anyadvise please. thank you
The good working code:
import gi
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
# gi.require_version("GstApp", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst #, GstApp

current_datetime = datetime.now()
dt = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
print(dt)

Gst.init()

pipeRGB =(
    "v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! tee name=t "
    "t. ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='www.google.com live=1' "
    "t. ! queue ! videorate ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=1/30 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink name=sinkRGB"
)



pipelineRGB = Gst.parse_launch(pipeRGB)
print("Parsing RGB Pipeline")
pipelineRGB.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
print("RGB Pipeline playing")

try:
    while True:
        sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("""\r\n
    ============================
    Keyboard Interrupt received
    ============================
    Closing GStreamer Pipeline""")
    pipelineRGB.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    pass

print("Finished!")


the not very good working code:
import gi
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime


gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib

current_datetime = datetime.now()
dt = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
print(dt)

Gst.init()

pipeRGB = (
    "v4l2src io-mode=4 device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! tee name=t "
    "t. ! queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://zkms.waldwaechter.de/live/rgb live=1' "
    "t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink name=sinkRGB"
)

pipelineRGB = Gst.parse_launch(pipeRGB)
appsinkRGB = pipelineRGB.get_by_name("sinkRGB")

def on_new_sample(sink):
    sample = sink.emit("pull-sample")
    buf = sample.get_buffer()
    caps = sample.get_caps()
    array = np.ndarray(
        (caps.get_structure(0).get_value('height'),
         caps.get_structure(0).get_value('width'),
         3),
        buffer=buf.extract_dup(0, buf.get_size()),
        dtype=np.uint8)
    return array

appsinkRGB.connect("new-sample", on_new_sample)

actual_fps=30
actual_width=1920
actual_height=1080

date_string= time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
gst_writer_str = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 !  queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc maxperf-enable=1 preset-level=4 control-rate=1 bitrate=8000000 ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=RGB_' + date_string + '.mp4' 
fourcc = 0 #RAW
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_writer_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fourcc, actual_fps, (actual_width, actual_height), True)
pipelineRGB.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
while True:
    frame = on_new_sample(appsinkRGB)
    if frame is not None:
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('RGB Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
pipelineRGB.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print("Finished!")

thank you for your help

note: previous questions by user give context

i'm working on a fire detection project with flir hadron camera and jetson nano computer ,i'm trying to display , save and stream the data from the camera i've been trying to this with gstreamer,opencv in python3 but with every code i try i'm losing frames for RGB data just by reading from the camera with opencv cap.read() . so what i'm trying to do in the working code is streaming to the server with the first code it works perfectly because i'm nor using opencv and also send data throught an appsink so that i can recieve them with an appsrc for the displaying and saving data

but when i tried that in the second code it's not working very well the display and the stream are not smooth
